# Directly access Sprite after swf embed

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite, embedding

I have the following class:

```
package  {
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
 import flash.ui.Keyboard;

 public class Ship extends Sprite {
  private var parentStage:Sprite;
  public var ship:Sprite;
  [Embed(source = '../lib/ship.swf')] private var swfShip:Class;
  public function Ship(parent:Sprite) {
   this.parentStage = parent;
   ship = new swfShip();
   parent.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
   parent.addChild(ship);
  }

  private function keyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
   switch (e.keyCode) {
    case Keyboard.RIGHT:
     ship.x += 10;
    break;
    default:

    break;
   }
  }

 }

}
```

But to access the sprite properties from outside this class, I have to do something like

```
ship = new Ship(this);
ship.ship.y = 320;
ship.ship.x = 320;
```

Is there a way to access the properties directly? I tried making *this = new new swfShip()* but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your `Ship` class won't extend `Sprite` (you really don't need to extend it according to your code) the best way'd be:

```
 public class Ship{
  private var parentStage:Sprite;
  public var ship:Sprite;
  //...
  public function set x(newval: int):void{
     //check value
     ship.x = newval;
  }

  public function set y(newval: int):void{
     //check value
     ship.y = newval;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You created class which extends Sprite, but it only adds other sprite (ship) to given parent. It contains ship, but it isn't the ship itself. Make Ship `addChild(ship)` to itself and then use `new Ship()` as you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can add method `setPosition(x:int, y:int)` to do this more easily. 
Also you can use `with` statement (see for example [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/statements.html#with) for details)